# Gluon 5.0.0 - Bottom Navigation Button new "selected" property

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

We recently changed to Gluon 5.0.0 and had to refactor a lot of code - also the Bottom Navigation Buttons, which do extend "Button" now (instead of "ToggleButton").

This led to problems with CSS files, which we were able to resolve.

However, we were not able to resolve one particular thing:

When adding two buttons at the bottom, one of them "lights" up while the other one does not (slightly greyish). ScenicView showed the property "selected", which we actually never set. The left button goes back, while the right one goes to the next view.
With those changes in Gluon 5.0.0, the first button is selected.

Since we want to show our users that they should go forward (so the right button) and we did not found a solution to mark the right one as selected.

Is there an easier way to achieve this instead of going into every view and add "btn.setSelected(true)" for every button?

Comment: It seems you have a BN for every view with 2 buttons and you want the right button to be the default selection in BN, right? In case, this is what you want, how were you achieving the same behaviour prior to 5.0.0?

Comment: Exactly!
There was no special thing to achieve it in the prior version, since it used to be a "ToggleButton", so it did get selected when clicking on it and not before...
I was checking out the BottomNavigationButton class and honestly thought about modifying the class itself for my usage.

Comment: BN is mostly used to switch views. When you are showing a BN, there must be an active view and the button related to the current view must be active. In your use case, I would suggest to switch to a custom control instead of BN.

Comment: May I ask what you mean with "... button related to the current view must be active."? Because for my understanding, both are related to the current view (they are shown in this exact view) but also they are not related regarding the functionality - they point to the previous or the next view.

Thanks for the recommendation with the custom control - since we have other things which are more important, we might probably just switch to the old BN, since it worked as expected. :)

Comment: If you spend some time reading the material design specification for [BottomNavigation](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html), you will find that its main purpose is to navigate between views and each button represents a specific view. These views are mostly the primary destinations in an application. For example: Check [Instagram app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android). Also, my interpretation might be wrong and I am open to opinions regarding this.

Comment: Again, since you said that the buttons in your BN point to previous and next view, it seems to me that you do not need toggle buttons or BNB, since previous/next view buttons shouldn't have a selected state. Instead of BN, use a HBox with 2 buttons in it ;) These buttons can have the same action that BN buttons used to have previously.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Haven't thought of it that way :) Thank you for the explanation!

I will then create a custom control with exactly this and try to make it clever, so I don't have to rename it everywhere :)